# plots won't show at the center of viewer

Tags: texstudio

Plots in TeXstudio won't show at the center of the viewer. There are a lot more blank space on the left than right. see below picture.

Is there a instruction I can use to set the position of origin O(0,0) of the coordinate plane?

how can I fix this?

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
    \draw[thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);
    \draw[->] (-8,0) -- (8,0) node[below right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-8) -- (0,8) node[above left] {$y$};
    \draw [black, line width = 0.50mm] plot[smooth,domain=-8:8] (\x, {\x}) node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
...
...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've just updated the question with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Fran gave the explanation of why this occurs (you can see it with `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`).

Another option, instead of telling the `tikzpicture` what it's margins should be, is wrapping it within `\makebox[\textwidth]{...your tikz picture...}`.  Then, using `\centering` just before the tikz picture.

This approach does not reduce the margins.  It also does not reduce the picture.  Instead, it *ignores* the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%\noindent% You may or may not want to uncomment this, depending on need
\makebox[\textwidth]{\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
    \draw[thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);
    \draw[->] (-8,0) -- (8,0) node[below right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-8) -- (0,8) node[above left] {$y$};
    \draw [black, line width = 0.50mm] plot[smooth,domain=-8:8] (\x, {\x}) node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture within \makebox and centered]

You can also remove the paragraph indent using `\noindent` just before `\makebox`. I included it, but commented it out, because your picture looked better indented due to the text on the right side of the image.  This is a matter of preference/need.

Comment: this technique yield the result that I wanted. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The image is placed at the left margin but symply is too big, so invade the right margin. Options: Reduce the margins or reduce the image. One way for the second option:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.8cm,y=.8cm]
    \draw[thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);
    \draw[->] (-8,0) -- (8,0) node[below right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-8) -- (0,8) node[above left] {$y$};
    \draw [black, line width = 0.50mm] plot[smooth,domain=-8:8] (\x, {\x}) node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the cause of the problem